# How to get video file URL from Twitter

Tags: javascript, websites

I am looking how to find the video URL of a Twitter video so I can code a converter later (using nodejs or something), but I can't figure out how to do this. I saw [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/how-to-get-video-url-from-embedded-link-in-twitter) but it doesn't really clear anything up (I can't figure out where the json file they are talking about is)
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You want to find video link of particular tweet or a generic solution?

Comment: a generic solution, I am trying to incorporate this into a nodejs (technically discord.js) program